# How do you disabled a button while a form doesn't validate with jQuery validate?

Tags: jquery, validation

I was wondering how you can disable button (not submit) with jQuery while a form doesn't validate with jQuery validate, but when it does validate, enabled the button.

Comment: Please elaborate what u want to ask?? 
Are you asking something like this:
There is a form having a validate button, once form has been validated u want to enable a "NEXT" button else this "NEXT" button is disabled.. or u asking something else...!!!

Comment: Oh yeah, my Bad. The form has a button that just executes some JS, but it needs to be disabled until the form validates. The button starts off disabled, and just needs jQuery validate code to enable it once the entire form validates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$("#myform").validate();
$("#submit").click(function() {
    if ($("#myform").valid())
        $('#button').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: thanks! I actually binded it to the blur method, it works just as well, except it doesn't require an extra button!

Answer (score 0):

That's a little tricky to do. What I'd suggest trying is binding an [`change()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change) event:

```
$(":input").change(function() {
  $('#formid").validate();
  if ($("#formid").valid()) {
    $("#buttonid").removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
    $("#buttonid").attr("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

The weakness of this method is that, for example, if a text field can't be blank the `change()` event won't be fired until it loses focus so the button won't be ungreyed. If this is important to you you could add a [`keydown()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keydown) event.

Comment: Small typo - I think line 5 should be '...removeAttr...". Also, if there is any change that you will add input fields dynamically, you can use the jquery "live" method rather than "change" to attach a listner to all input fields, even ones added after the page loads.